# Symfony2 : Entities not created in database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm making entities with Symfony2 and Doctrine2. I made some entities that represent a many-to-many relation between two of my entities.

An example of one of these entities :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Contact_Conference_Invitation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Aurae\UserBundle\Entity\Contact")
     */
    private $contact;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Aurae\ConferenceBundle\Entity\Conference")
     */
    private $conference;

    /**
     * @var datetime dateInvitation
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateInvitation", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateInvitation;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

I have tried updating my sql schema, but the tables corresponding to these entities do not appear. Is there somewhere I have to declare them (config or such)? If not, what's wrong?

Thanks a lot

Edit : I had forgotten the namespace for these class, and that's why they were omitted by Doctrine. Another case closed :) thanks for the answers!

Comment: do you have the mapping class as a use statement in the top `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`

Comment: Yep I have... Do I have to use the two classes I link as well?

Comment: No you don't.  You don't seem to have any `inversedBy="x"` statements in your manytoone declarations. Not sure that would fix it but its definately good practice.

Comment: And some join column statements too i guess: `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="conference_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL", nullable=true)`

Comment: Though these aren't inversed by anything at the moment. Should I make a $invitations array in contact and make it the inverse of $contact here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12393/discussion-between-luke-and-gabriel-theron)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assumptions ...**

No, you don't need to declare them anywhere else than in your Entity directory.

- What's the error message you got?
- I guess you added

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

on the top of your classes to let them be mapped.

**I tried ...**

I tried to generate your entities by adding a simple Contact & Conference entities and it's working fine.
Here are the code snippets:

**Contact_Conference_Invitation.php**

```
namespace Ahsio\StackBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Contact_Conference_Invitation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ahsio\StackBundle\Entity\Contact")
     */
    private $contact;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ahsio\StackBundle\Entity\Conference")
     */
    private $conference;

    /**
     * @var datetime dateInvitation
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateInvitation", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateInvitation;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**Contact.php**

```
namespace Ahsio\StackBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @param $id
     */    
    public  function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

**Conference.php**

```
namespace Ahsio\StackBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Conference
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @param $id
     */
    public  function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Here are the generated tables:

[image]

NB: I used a specific namespace for the entities generation to work fine, you need to change them.

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget to check that you have automapping enabled.

In your config.yml you should have

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Came across this question because my entities weren't generated as well, this was my issue, it could save some time to people struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the definition of your ManyToMany relation in the sample of code you provided.

As an example, here's a ManyToMany relationship I implemented for a project

**Entity Project.php**

```
/**
 * @var Provider[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Provider", mappedBy="projects")
 */
protected $providers = null;
```

**Entity Provider.php**

```
/**
 * @var Project[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="providers")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="PROVIDER_PROJECT")
 */
protected $projects = null;
```

As you can see, here you define the join table for your ManyToMany relationship.

Of course those entities are specific for my particular project but you get the idea and you can adapt it easily for your needs.

Comment: The OP's post uses an extra field in his many to many table so he cannot do it this way, his post is of his actual many to many table